# Using datediff in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table like below in Oracle  , Receive and Update date files data type is TimeStamp

```
Stock No       Receive Date                    Update Date
222            20-NOV-14 00.56.56.000000000    20-NOV-14 00.59.04.000000000
333            20-NOV-14 01.55.09.000000000    20-NOV-14 01.55.47.000000000
444            20-NOV-14 01.55.47.000000000    20-NOV-14 01.55.47.000000000
555            20-NOV-14 02.16.12.000000000    20-NOV-14 02.16.31.000000000
```

i want to write query to get results, those results will contain only time difference between receive date and update date more than one minute.

like

```
222            20-NOV-14 00.56.56.000000000     20-NOV-14 00.59.04.000000000
```

is it possible to use datediff function in Oracle to get above result.

Comment: What format are you looking for the result? hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: Something like `where Abs(ReceiveDate - UpdateDate) >= 1/1440` ?

Comment: I want rows where there is time difference is more than one minute  b/w receive date and update date. i want stock No's only no need to get all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function to return the difference since there is no datediff in oracle. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff (options   IN VARCHAR2,
                                     p_d1      IN DATE,
                                     p_d2      IN DATE)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   l_result   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT   (p_d2 - p_d1)
          * DECODE (UPPER (options),
                    'SS', 24 * 60 * 60,
                    'MI', 24 * 60,
                    'HH', 24,
                    NULL)
     INTO l_result
     FROM DUAL;

   RETURN l_result;
END;
```

The OPTIONS variable tells the function what I want to return, so ss = seconds, mi= minutes, hh=hour.

Then I would change you original query to:

```
Select * from myTable where datediff ('ss', Receive_Date, Update_Date) >= 60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from the_table
where receive_date - update_date >= interval '1' minute;
```

This assumes that the two columns *really* are `timestamp`. Because only then the difference between two timestamps yields an `interval`.

If you want a different timespan, use a different interval:

```
select *
from the_table
where receive_date - update_date >= interval '30' second;

select *
from the_table
where receive_date - update_date >= interval '1' hour;
```

If both columns are defined as `date` (which also includes a time in Oracle) the result of subtracting one from the other is an integer representing the difference in (fractional) days.

More details in the manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i48042